# Is there something like a Lightning Web Component Guidelines document?

Tags: lightning-web-components, sfdc-styleguide

Having done iOS app development, I have seen Apple's Guidelines document. It is very useful in instructing what makes a good app (and what not).

Is there something similar for LWC development? Anything is possible, but some solutions constitute a better User Experience than others. Specifically, I am faced with the decision to show some information on user request and I have several options, like displaying in a new tab or in a modal pop-up, on mouseover of after an explicit click. I am looking for the official recommendations of Salesforce.

Comment: We have SLDS Design guidelines,
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/overview/
They are generic and not specific to any technology like Aura/LWC/VF

Comment: I would check the SLDS guidelines above and mimic Salesforce's UX as much as possible provided what you're working on is a part of the usual Lightning Experience and not a custom application. The UX StackExchange (https://ux.stackexchange.com/) would also be helpful for a question like this. 
All UX needs to be considered from a user's perspective. What is the additional information? Is it going to be common for someone to need this information? Does blocking the screen with a modal present any issues to the user? Do they need to copy and paste text? All of these are important considerations.

Answer (score 1):

To start with

**LWC OSS**
lwc as open-source I would recommend [lwc dev](https://lwc.dev/) and for [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/overview/)

**LWC in salesforce**
After which there is the official [lwc Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc) which is great place to begin for implementations in salesforce and it covers in detail

- Introducing Lightning Web Components
- Create Lightning Web Components Communicate with Events Work with
- Salesforce Data Security with Lightning Locker Use Components in
- Salesforce Experiences Use Components Outside Salesforce with
- Lightning Out  Aura Coexistence Migrate Aura Components Debug
- Lightning Web Components Test Lightning Web Components Lifecycle
- Hooks
- [Lifecycle Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks)

Additionally, LWC components can also be tested/tried on the [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground). The [component library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) has all the base lightning components with samples that can be tried/viewed/tested on the playground.

The [developer blog article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/12/introducing-lightning-web-components-recipes-patterns-and-best-practices.html) is also a good place to start.

In General, the best practices would be:

- Using public, and private properties wisely (@api or @track annotations).
- **Parent to Child and sibling component Communication:**

  - There should be a single source of truth to data - always. So, you should be getting the data in the parent component
  - Usage of PubSub
  - Parent to child communication and vice versa
- Usage of Apex in LWC

  - It is recommended to use apex ONLY for getting the data and for DML statements with filter conditions and parameters.
  - Using [Lightning Data service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.data_ui_api) instead of the apex

    - For Minor Record operations(like create, delete, update, and refresh) [uiRecordApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_record) can be used
    - To get the records and metadata for a list view [uiListApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/reference_lightning_ui_api_list_ui.html) can be used
    - To get object metadata, and get picklist values [uiObjectInfoApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/reference_lightning_ui_api_object_info.html) can be used
- [Jest Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.testing), should be implemented for testing lightning web components

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer, but I don't think you completely understood my question. You explain how to do LWC development in general, but my question is on how to make a usable/user friendly component that is inline with Lightning Experience.

Comment: ahh!! My bad then 

Comment: @SanderdeJong SLDS is basically similar to, for example, Google's Material Design, Apple's Guidelines, etc. Yes, it has a bunch of components, but it also has a lot of "rules" about how to build the UI, such as placeholders while loading, how charts should be colored and rendered, etc.

Comment: Yep, I have worked with SLDS. I misunderstood the question as best practices for creating lightning web components... There are design guidelines which might be helpful https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/overview/ but unfortunately, they don't talk about all the elements in detail